# How can I read headlines from Times of India and place it into text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 and urllib2 command for doing this.But I am facing error that urllib2 has no attribute name urlopen.Please help me.thanx,Here is my code.

```
import urllib2
import re
pat = re.compile('target="_parent">(.*?)</a>')

url = 'http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/home/headlines'
sock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
li = pat.findall(sock.read())
sock.close()

print li

f=open("headlines.txt", 'a+')
for i in range(len(li)):
    f.write(li[i]+"\n")
f.close()
```

**Traceback**

```
Error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Training/PycharmProjects/758702_Python_Program/ReadTOI/ReadTOI.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib2
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 111, in <module>
    from urllib import (unwrap, unquote, splittype, splithost, quote,
  File "C:\Users\Training\PycharmProjects\758702_Python_Program\urllib.py", line 4, in <module>
    f=urllib.urlopen("http://www.python.org/")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
File "C:\Users\Training\PycharmProjects\758702_Python_Program\urllib.py", line 4, in <module>
```

It looks like you have an other file by the name `urllib.py` in your working directory. When doing an `import urllib` python is importing your local file which does not contain `urlopen()`. Renaming your local file to something else or changing your working directory would solve this

Comment: There is one more issue.Can you please solve this?It gives proxy server error:IOError: ('http error', 407, 'Proxy Authorization Required', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x0183A8F0>)

Comment: Use BeautifulSoup along with urllib2

Comment: @Anil This exception is being raised as your not logged in. you can login with your webpage user credentials following this article (https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#id6)

Comment: you don't need to be logged in to access the content.